# stopPropagation doesn't work in flex

Tags: apache-flex, events, event-handling

i have a root component A and two component B , C that C is front of B

B and C have EventListener

```
B.addEventLisener(MouseEvent.MouseDown,handler1);
C.addEventLisener(MouseEvent.MouseDown,handler2);
```

i want when c catch the event it doesn't bubble to B

i use

```
private function handler2(e:MouseEvent):void{
e.stopPropagation();
allowDraw = true;}
```

in handler2 but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 2):

Seems, that C and B are children of A. But if C is not child of B, it will not bubble from C to B. Bubbling works only from child to parent. But if B and C are both children of A and you added C after B, it doesn't mean that C became child of B.

That's why event handlers are executed in order they are added. You have 2 solutions:

1.swap adding handlers

```
C.addEventLisener(MouseEvent.MouseDown,handler2);
B.addEventLisener(MouseEvent.MouseDown,handler1);
```

2.use [event priorities](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_09.html)

```
B.addEventLisener(MouseEvent.MouseDown,handler1, false, 10);
C.addEventLisener(MouseEvent.MouseDown,handler2, false, 20);
```

Moreover, `stopPropagation` won't work as well. You'll need to remove listener.

**UPD**

If you don't want to remove listeners, use boolean flag;

```
private function handler2(e:MouseEvent):void {
    e.stopPropagation();
    allowDraw = true;
    stop = true;
}

private function handler1(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if (stop) {
        stop = false;
        return;
    }
    //handler code
}
```

Comment: your first solution doesn't possible because of the logic of my program and about your second solution : is handler1 still call?

Comment: @sami yes, you'll need to do B.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handler1); in handler2

Comment: Oh so bad! i cant do this! i need B and C both have their event Listeners all the time :(

Comment: Would the [stopImmediatePropgration()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#stopImmediatePropagation()) method be another solution? I don't do this often enough to know, but it seems like another solution (the one posted here seems fine too!).

Comment: @Timofei it's a good solution but unfortunately it's not solve my problem because B and C are two separate components and it's not possible to pass stop parameter to them!